# Switching Style for more than one Print item (like escape sequences)

Tags: color, customization, printing

I know about the possibility to use `Style` in `Print` to influence the color of the next item, e.g.

```
Print[
 Style["this prints red ", Red], 
 "now back to default black ", 
 Style["this prints green ", Green]
]
```

I just want to print some lines in an extended output with some other color but I want to avoid to enclose every single item in e.g. `Style[item, color]`.

What I am after:

Something to mix into a `Print` statement that applies for the rest of this particular `Print` statement up to the next style switching item in it but not beyond the end of this particular `Print` statement. Something like the well known *escape sequences* control printers which use character fonts rather than graphics raster printing.

Answer (score 4):

A little bit unclear to me but maybe this:

```
foo = Print @@ (Style[Row[{##2}], #] & @@@ (Split[#, 
       Not@MatchQ[#2, _Directive] &])) &

foo @ {  Directive[Red], "this prints", "red ", Directive[{}], "now back", 
 "to default black ",  Directive[Green], "this prints green"
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 In case OP is interested in giving colors only, the `Split` expression could be changed to `Split[#, Not@ColorQ[#2] &]`.

Comment: @Xavier yep, wanted to keep that more flexible but good reminder.

Comment: Yes, Kuba, I was after something like what you provided. Your version even works for more than one feature like colour and bold: foo @ {  Directive[Red], "this prints N[Pi] in red:", N[Pi], 
  Directive[{}], " now back", 
   "to default", Directive[Bold], " black ",  Directive[Green], 
  "this prints", Directive[{Green, Bold}], " green"
  }. It woks find, but how does it do that? I tried to decompose your fancy function foo, but I did not get the clue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would it be possible to reformulate the function foo to a function called PRINT such that it can be used like this: PRINT["this modifies Print to switch to  ", Directive[Red], " red ",N[Pi,10], "...", Directive[{}]," that's it."]? Would it be possible to automatically apply List  to provide Kuba's form of arguments, i.e. a list of arbitrary length instead of arbitrarily many arguments?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen Hi, sorry for a delay, I'm encouraging you to try it step by step. First use `Split...` part on an example input, then `@@@` with `Style`. It should become clearer, if not feel free to ask further :)

Comment: Kuba: Hi, I tried(Split[#, Not@MatchQ[#2, _Directive] &]) @ {Directive[Red], 
  "printing ", Directive[Red], "red. ", Directive[{}], "Now back ", 
  "to default black ", Directive[{Green, Bold, Underlined}], 
  "Geen and italic 15pt underl."} to get Slot[#1][{Directive[
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], "printing ", Directive[
RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], "red. ", Directive[{}], "Now back ", 
  "to default black ", 
  Directive[{RGBColor[0, 1, 0], Bold, Underlined}], 
  "Geen and italic 15pt underl."}].  I see nothing grouped by Split in it. What is the purpose of Split here?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen you forgot about `&`, be careful: `Split[#, Not@MatchQ[#2, _Directive] &] &@{Directive[Red], ...}`.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen p.s. please take a [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica problems like this are often easily solve by writing simple functions that act as shortcuts for tedious typing. In your case, you could write

```
red[txt_] := Style[txt, Red]
grn[txt_] := Style[txt, Green]

Print[
  red @ "this prints red ",
  "now back to default black ",
  grn @ "this prints green "]
```